# How to use Instafeed.js to pull in hashtag posts from your own page after June 1st update

Tags: instagram-api, instafeedjs

I'm using Instafeed.js.

Using instructions from https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
    userId: 'username',
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'tagname',
    clientId: 'CLIENTID',
    accessToken: 'ACCESSTOKEN',
    limit: 10
});
feed.run();
```

Error message:
[image]

When trying to get the permissions, no matter which option I select it brings up a red error message (even "Other") and no one to contact for support.

[image]

How can I get the public content scope, or simply, how can post our specific hashtagged images?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, you cannot really do this anymore, for a couple reasons...

First note that you're confusing scopes with "sandbox mode". Here's [a short summary of what you can and cannot do with the Instagram API](https://medium.com/@emersonthis/instagram-on-websites-the-new-landscape-62c91d733894#.4z8g35g2s) since the June 1st rules took effect.

TL;DR

Instagram no longer permits the use of it's API for most of the use cases that developers used to be able to use it for. Unless your app is doing one of a coulpe very specific things, you will never get it approved (out of Sandbox mode).

But this is not the reason that you're seeing that error. The error message is telling you that when you generated the token you did not request it with the `public_content` scope. If you used one of the handful of tools to manually generate the auth token, this is likely your problem because most of them are designed to just give you an auth token with `basic` scope. This only has permission to see your own profile etc. Not anyone else's.

Finally, keep in mind that even if you generate the token with the correct scopes, you probably are not going to see the results you expect because apps in Sandbox mode *only* can see content from the Sandbox users. So you will only see recently tagged posts from just a handful of people that you've invited to be Sandbox users. This is explained more holistically in the article linked above.

Comment: Good resource thanks for sharing. Bummer on the hashtags! Will just have to do manually I guess... Orrrrr maybe create a script to crawl em.